# Python to Mathematica code bug

Tags: conversion, python, broken-code

I have an assignment in Mathematica, which I've already solved using Python and it's a bit hard to convert the code. Here's what I have done so far:

```
def sigmoid(x): # define the sigmoid function
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-x))

def pos_list(node): # returns the neighborhood of node, A is a matrix of adjacency
    return np.nonzero(A[node])[1]  

def neg_list(node): # returns nodes that are not neighbors
    return np.where(A[node]==0)[1]
```

I have these in Mathematica:

```
sigmoid[x_] := 1 / (1 + Exp[-x])
M := AdjacencyMatrix[undirectedEdges] (* this is A from above*)
posList[n_] := M[[n]]["NonzeroPositions"]
negList[n_] := Flatten[Position[Normal[M[[n]]], x_Integer /; x = 0]]
```

Now there is a longer function:

```
def next_choice(v,t,p,q):
    positive = pos_list(v)
    li = np.array([])
    for pos in positive:
        if pos==t:
            li = np.append(li,1/p)
        elif pos in pos_list(t):
            li = np.append(li,1)
        else :
            li = np.append(li,1/q)
    prob = li/li.sum()
    return np.random.choice(positive,1,p=prob)[0]
```

So I am stuck here. This is what I've written:

```
nextChoice[v_, t_, p_, q_] := 
 Module[{li, vpositive, tpositive, len, i, prob},
  li = List[];
  vpositive = posList[v];
  tpositive = posList[t];
  len = Length[vpositive];
  For[i = 1, i <= len, i++,
   If[vpositive[[i]][[1]] == t, AppendTo[li, 1/p], 
     If[Length[AnyTrue[tpositive, # == vpositive[[i]][[1]] &] > 0], 
      AppendTo[li, 1], AppendTo[li, 1/q]]];
   ];
  prob = li/Total[li];
  Return[RandomChoice[prob -> vpositive, 1][[1]]]
  ]
```

This list `li` only has one element and I cannot figure out why it doesn't go through all the if statements. any ideas?

Edit: an example

```
mat = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0} , {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}};
M = SparseArray[mat]
```

If we call nextChoice[1, 3, 0.5, 0.5], it should return a random node from the positive list.

Comment: Without any example input, it will be hard to tell what exactly is going on. That being said: `Position[...,x_Integer/;x==0]` can be `Position[...,0]`, `List[]` can be `{}`. I'd write your for loop using `Map`, or using `Table` (as `Table[...,{pos, vpositive}]` You don't need `Return`, the last expression will always be returned. It looks like the issue is in `If[Length[AnyTrue[...]>0],...]`. The result will always be `If[2,...]` (because `Length[True>0]` is `2`), which will stay unevaluated because `2` is not a boolean. I'd also suggest to replace the entire condition with `MemberQ[...]`

Comment: Thank you so much for the suggestions. I did correct the `negativeList`,`[]` and rewrote the condition to `If[MemberQ[tpositive,vpositive[[i]][[1]]]`. There is still something wrong. I am not sure how to use `Map` or `Table`, since the if statement is not a function that I can define before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's my attempt at fixing your code:

```
mat = {{0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1, 0, 0}};
M = SparseArray[mat]

sigmoid[x_] := 1/(1 + Exp[-x])
posList[n_] := Flatten[M[[n]]["NonzeroPositions"]]
negList[n_] := Flatten[Position[Normal[M[[n]]], 0]]

nextChoice[v_, t_, p_, q_] :=
 Module[
  {vpositive, tpositive, prob},
  vpositive = posList[v];
  tpositive = posList[t];
  prob = Table[
    Which[pos == t,
     1/p,
     MemberQ[tpositive, pos],
     1,
     True,
     1/q
     ],
    {pos, vpositive}
    ];
  RandomChoice[prob -> vpositive]
  ]

nextChoice[1, 3, 0.5, 0.5]
(* 2 *)
```

I won't go over all the changes (feel free to ask in the comments if something is unclear), but here are some of them:

- I changed `posList` to return a list of indices with the same format as `negList`
- I switched from the `For` loop to a [`Table`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Table.html)
- Rather than appending one element to `li` per loop iteration, I simply use the list returned by `Table`
- I swapped the nested `If` to [`Which`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Which.html)
- You don't need to normalize the weights given to `RandomChoice`
- If you don't specify `1` sample for `RandomChoice`, it will give you a single sample without a list by default
- I switched the broken condition to use [`MemberQ`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MemberQ.html)

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I really appreciate it! I understand all the changes that you have made, it looks very neat.

Comment: @chris I have to do a lot of other parts for this assignment, but I needed an extra push towards the right direction. I hope you didn't mean it in a sarcastic way :)

Comment: @mandella Good luck with your assignment! One other thing to note: Take a look at `Echo`, it's an amazing tool to help you debug functions, since you can easily monitor steps of a calculation

Comment: Thank you very much! :) Great I will check `Echo` I think I will need that tool a lot in order to finish this task successfully :) Thank you also for this note!